# Linux find exec md5sum, only the sum like this (fullpath TAB size TAB mtime TAB ctime TAB md5)

Tags: find, exec, md5sum

I want to view for the files in /var/www the following data:
fullpath size mtime ctime md5

I ran the following command:

```
find /var/www/ -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -printf '%p\t%s\t%t\t%c\t' -exec md5sum {}  \;
```

which gives me:
(fullpath size mtime ctime md5 fullpath)

```
/var/www/intranet/admin/tpl/view.tpl.php        1448    Wed Dec 16 18:51:06.0000000000 2015     Fri Sep 15 09:08:36.0805775786 2017     e0b7dacaf7c90fb0fbe7a69c331e36aa  /var/www/intranet/admin/tpl/view.tpl.php
```

How can I filter the last fullpath?????? I do not want to show it. All fields are TAB separated.

I tried:

```
find /var/www/  -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -printf '%p\t%s\t%t\t%c\t'
   -exec md5sum {} | awk '{print $1}'\;
```

for which I received the error: "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

```
find /var/www/ -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -printf '%p\t%s\t%t\t%c\t' -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}'
```

for which I got only the md5sum.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipelines (`|`) are a shell-feature.  To get shell features, one needs to invoke a shell:

```
find /var/www -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -printf '%p\t%s\t%t\t%c\t' -exec sh -c 'md5sum "$1" | awk '\''{print $1}'\' MD5 {} \;
```

Or, if you prefer commands spread over multiple lines:

```
find /var/www \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    ! -type d \
    -printf '%p\t%s\t%t\t%c\t' \
    -exec sh -c 'md5sum "$1" | awk '\''{print $1}'\' MD5 {} \;
```

#### Notes

1. `sh -c somestring` invokes a shell and instructs it to execute whatever commands are in `somestring`.
2. `sh -c somestring MD5 {}` invokes the shell and executes somestring **and** assigns `$0` to MD5 and `$1` to whatever `find` substitutes for `{}`.

   `$0` is only used by the shell when it creates error messages and otherwise unimportant.
3. A complication is that our command, `somestring`, must contain both single quotes and double-quotes which is why we need escaped single-quotes.

   In our case, we want `somestring` to be:

   ```
   md5sum "$1" | awk '{print $1}'
   ```

   To prevent the main shell from substituting in for `$1`, we need to put this inside single-quotes.  However, we can't put single-quotes inside single-quotes.  The workaround is to use this for our single-quoted string:

   ```
   'md5sum "$1" | awk '\''{print $1}'\'
   ```